# Xcode: Editing a Package Dependency of a Package project

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode13

This [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package) explains how to check out a modifiable repo of a package dependency used by a traditional Xcode project to let you edit the package directly in your project. However, it doesn't seem to work if your host project is also a Package and not a traditional Xcode project.

Is there a way to edit a dependency in that case?

**Update:** Seems like it’s possibly a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010706/xcode-13-1-bug-editing-dependency-as-local) in Xcode 13.1.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010706/xcode-13-1-bug-editing-dependency-as-local ?

Comment: Yup, sure seems to be, thanks.

Comment: Not that it's all that much help! Just trying to keep birds of a feather flocking together... :)