# Editing a Package Dependency as a Local Package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

### Overview

- I have a project that uses a remote swift package.
- I would like to edit this package in the same project so that I can refine it based on the usage.

### Aim:

- To do this I am trying to add the same package as a local package so that I can edit it.

### Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package

### Problem:

- When I drag and drop the cloned folder containing `Package.swift` into the project, I can't see any of the local package source files in the project. (see screenshot)

[image: Xcode Project with Swift Package]

I have been breaking my head over it. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

### Xcode Version:

- `13.2 (13C90)` (downloaded from the developer portal not the AppStore)

Comment: Have you got the package open in another Xcode window?

Comment: Wow!!! Spot on, could you please post that as an answer, would be helpful to others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you cannot see the content of the package is that you have it open in another Xcode instance.

You can only edit a package in one Xcode instance at a time.

I find closing down Xcode completely, then opening up the particular project that I want to edit the package in solves the problem.

Comment: Amazing!!, thanks a ton was breaking my head over it. I remember now that a similar thing happens even with frameworks as well